# Add or Remove roles for a current user when debugging in asp.net core using Identity?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I would like to change the role of the current logged user for testing purposes, I don't know where I can do it and how to add and remove claims to the current claims collection

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to register a custom [`IClaimsTransformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-3.0) where you can create a custom principal and change his identity/claims/roles as you need.

The `IClaimsTransformation` service, if exists, will be invoked after the request has been authenticated successfully.

I create a custom transformation that takes effect only in Development environment as below:

```cs
public class CustomClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;

    // if you're using 3.0, use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead
    public CustomClaimsTransformation(IHostingEnvironment env) 
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!NeedChangeClaims(principal)) 
            return Task.FromResult(principal);

        var identity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        // filter claims (i.e. remove claims)
        var claims= identity.Claims
            .Where(c => !ShouldRemoveThisClaim(c));     
        // map a new identity
        identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, identity.AuthenticationType, identity.RoleClaimType,identity.NameClaimType);
        // add extra claims as you like
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.StreetAddress,"NY"));

        return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }

    private bool NeedChangeClaims(ClaimsPrincipal cp) 
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) { 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool ShouldRemoveThisClaim(Claim c) 
    {
        if (c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value == "FIAdmin")
            return true;
        if (c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value == "HRAdmin")
            return true;
        if (c.Type == ClaimTypes.OtherPhone)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

To enable this service, we need also register it in Startup:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, CustomClaimsTransformation>();
```